# How to split $ from javascript value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to split the `$` symbol from `i variable` and display the value like `20` not like `,20`.

The code I use for this:

```
<script>
    var i = "$20";
    var j= "10";
    var values=i.split('$');
    var v = values;
    var sum=parseInt(v)+j;
    document.write(sum);
</script>
```

How do I split the value without comma?

Comment: you should pass the 2nd argument to `parseInt`.

Comment: `replace()` is what you want, not split.

Comment: what is the expected out put?

Answer (score 3):

```
var i = "$20",
    j= "10",
    v = i.replace(/\D/g,''),
    sum = parseInt(v, 10)+parseInt(j, 10);
document.getElementById('output').textContent = sum;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/utKaY/1/).

Edited (belatedly) to address the problems of that particular regular expression removing any `.` or `,` characters (to denote decimals):

```
var i = "$20.23",
    j= "10",
    v = i.replace(/[$£€]/g,''),
    sum = parseFloat(v) + parseInt(j, 10);
document.getElementById('output').textContent = sum;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/utKaY/).

References:

- [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: +1 - This is obviously the way to do it, why would you use split to remove a character

Comment: @adeneo: thanks, that was pretty much my thinking too (after "why all those `var` declarations?", and "where's the radix?")...

Comment: Yeah splitting seems dumb, also it's probably safer to use `parseFloat` though...

Comment: That replace will be a problem if `"$20"` is, say, `"$20.00"` - `\D` will strip the `.`, and it'll be `2000` instead of `20`.

Comment: @Brad: yeah, I know. I forgot to add in an alternative that simply strips out currency symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var i = "$20";
var j = "10";
var values = i.split('$');  // Creates an array like ["", "20"]
var v = values[1];          // Get the 2nd element in the array after split
var sum = parseInt(v, 10) + parseInt(j, 10);
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't parse it just perform the addition directly:

```
var i = 20;
var j = 10;
var sum = i + j; // use parseInt() if it's defined as a string - see below
// var i = "$20".replace(/\$/g,'');
// var j = "30";
// var sum = parseInt(i) + parseInt(j)
```

Also if you have to replace some character in a string use replace():

```
i = i.replace(/\$/g,'')
```

Comment: That regex should be `/\$/`, `$` is a special character.  Also, not doing a `parseInt()` would yield a result of `"2010"`.

Answer (score 0):

check this it work fine [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qQezQ/)

```
var i = "$20";
var j = "10";
var values = i.split('$');
var v = values[1];
var sum = parseInt(v) + parseInt(j);
alert(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var i = "$20"
   ,j = "10"
   ,sum = +j + +i.slice(1);
//=> sum = 30
```